# How to identify number of vertices, edges and weights in a cellular network

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a cellular network then what are the vertices, edges and edges weights in this network. I have choose customers as vertices. Customers calling each other as edges. Time of duration each two customers spend as edge weight. Is this the right approach? Thank you

Comment: It depends on what you're trying to do. Are you trying to model this based on background knowledge? What's the purpose? Or maybe you have data and you want to infer the network structure. It really depends on what you want to do and what you have.

Comment: This is my paper question which I attempted yesterday. I want to know if I did it right or wrong. teacher question was same as I defined in the title of this question. I wrote vertices as customers, edges as two people calling or called each other inside a network and edges weight as total time two customers spend during a call.

Answer (score 3):

If by the right approach you want to know if it's reasonable to model the relationship between users of a cellphone network, yes, it makes sense.

Every vertex is a device (customer), an edge illustrates a relationship between devices (such as calls) and the weight of each edge is the duration of each communication.

Alternatively, you could have transmission towers as vertices, an edge between each set of towers that are within their reach, and the weight would be the number of phone calls that occurred between two antennas.

As you can see, there are many ways in which you can model this through graphs.

Comment: It's a very helpful answer, I appreciate this. Thank you

Comment: Thank you for spending the time to write this message, @zahid. I'm glad it was helpful.